# Polymer : Alternate color depending on user role (admin, common user, speical user)

Tags: css, polymer

I'd like to ask if someone can put me on a lead. I'd like to use different style sheet in function of the user 'role' into a polymer app.
First I tried to use data-binding on the `<style include='shared-styles'>`
I tried :  `<style include='{{sharedStyle}}'>`. But as expected it didn't work.

So.. Can someone explain me how to begin in this field ? (event the key word to look for in google, I can't find anything really relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS variables,

```
.admin {
   --app-color: #123
}
.user {
   --app-color: #456
}
```

Now declare a master container add with js add class by user type

```
<div id="master"> </div>
```

and apply with

```
element {
   color : var(--app-color);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, smooth and easy :)